# 8 dirs movement, how to correctly display proper image for each direction?

Tags: c#, .net, image, properties

I am making simple top down game. There are 8 possible directions of car so I want to assign proper image to display for each direction.

My idea: Pass 8 images to Car class (like an array of bitmaps)
In the Position_X and Position_Y properties I could in the Set accessor determine which direction is now to be displayed and select the proper image.
Would it make sense?

```
class Car
{
    Bitmap ImageToDisplay;

    Bitmap left;
    Bitmap right;
    ...
    public Car(Bitmap [] dirImages)
    {
      left=dirImages[0];
      right=dirImages[1];
      ..etc

    }

    public int POSITION_X 
    { 
        set
        {
           if (POSITION_X>value)
               ImageToDisplay=left;
           else ImageToDisplay=right;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me, letting the object determine its direction and expose the proper image through a public method. But I've never designed a 2d or 3d game before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue for [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
If this was your complete Car class this would be OK, but I assume your Car class will do some more work.

Inspired from my latest adventures with WPF and databinding I would propose that the Car class exposes a property `Direction`, preferably with an `enum` describing your 8 directions. Then you have a separate converter class that converts the `Direction` to a bitmap.

By breaking out the actual bitmap selection from the Car class you separate the logic (calculation of the direction) with presentation (selection of the appropriate bitmap).
This way you can reuse the `Direction` properties for other purposes, like calculation where the car moves and when figuring out how user input should affect the car movement.

There is nothing technically wrong with your code, but there is a big risk that you end up with a huge car class that does to many things at once. A warning sign might be that when your `POSITION_X` setter besides updating `ImageToDisplay` updates five other properties too.

Comment: Well but if the Car exposes just direction, how could some separate class know which image to load? That would work only if that convert class worked just for Car class.

Comment: @Coco, yes, that would be a specially crafted class for the Car object (or at least it has to know how to convert the enum type of the `Direction`property). You may call it `CarDirectionToImageConverter` if you like. The purpose is to remove as much stuff as possible from the actual logic of how the car moves.

Comment: Agreed. Keep the 'presentation' layer separate from the 'business' layer. The Car object knows about the internal state of the car, and its' recognisable external properties (such as speed and direction). Something 'higher up', in the presentation logic part of the game loop, should be asking all Cars what their disposition is and then making decisions about how to represent that on a screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a separate function that is called whenever the rotation of the object changes, and that function would know, based on the objects rotation, which image should be the "active" image, and how to update the objects display and private "currentImage" property.